# Почему теряется контекст в методе ES6 класса React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';

export default class Text extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      isOpened: false,
    };
  }

  toggleOpening() {
    this.setState((prevState) => ({
      isOpened: !prevState.isOpened
    }));
  }

  render() {

    return ( 
           <div onClick = {this.toggleOpening} >
               Toggle Opening 
           </div>
    );
  }
}
```

При клике на div в консоли выскакивает ошибка 'this is undefined'. В чистом JS при создании класса, его метод корректно ссылается на экземпляр объекта. Почему так?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

используйте анонимную функцию

```
toggleOpening = () => {
    this.setState((prevState) => ({
      isOpened: !prevState.isOpened
    }));
  }
```

либо биндите её в конструкторе

```
this.toggleOpening = this.toggleOpening.bind(this);
```

Офф-документация https://ru.reactjs.org/docs/faq-functions.html#bind-in-render

Comment: Я знаю, что нужно биндить, но зачем? Почему теряется контекст?

Comment: В js всё работает точно так. this имеет не лексическую область видимости и привязывается при вызове.